# Is there any way to make a text file that no users can read?

Tags: linux, files, permissions, root

My question is very simple: Is there any way to make a text file that no users can read or write to, including `root`?

Comment: I'm think you can do it with access control lists (ACL), though I'm not sure how.

Comment: Simple answer is no.  You can stop root from accessing (or modifying access) to  your file.

Comment: Maybe this is a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: No. I'm not trying to solve a problem, I'm trying specifically to make a text file no users can read. I'm mostly just wondering if it's possible, and how to do it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would the purpose of such a file be? I mean if you **could** do this, then you (as a user), nor anyone else could read it or write to it... so what would its purpose be?

Comment: Are you _actually_ asking about encryption?

Comment: I'm not asking about encryption, and there isn't much purpose, it's just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to completely stop `root` from reading or modifying a file or directory. `root` can do those things even without any permissions and ACLs can be modified and removed by `root`. This would also be the case if permissions did stop `root` from reading or modifying the the file because `root` could just change the permissions or ownership. The file could be put on an NFS export with root squash but `root` could still `su` to a user with permissions and read it that way. The same thing could be done with other protocols. Even SELinux can just be disabled by `root`. That's the point of having a superuser.

Rather than attempting in vain to stop `root` from accessing or reading files, the best thing to do is to not put data that you don't want being read on that particular system. This isn't entirely possible in an enterprise environment because the System Engineers/System Admins who have access to everything would still be able to get to it but it's the only way to do it for others who have `root`.

Answer (score 0):

No. Traditionally root is all-powerful, can read/write whatever she likes, regardless of permissions. That is the whole point: be omnipotent as the "owner" of the system.

There are ways using non-Unix permission models (like SELinux) to divide up permissions, but that isn't "Unix" per se.